# The argparse code snippet only print part log

Tags: python, pycharm, argparse

I have a code for testing `argparse` module function:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.description='give me two number, I will return the product'
parser.add_argument("-a","--ParA", help="I am A",type=int)
parser.add_argument("-b","--ParB", help="I am B",type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.ParA:
    print("A is: ",args.ParA)
if args.ParB:
    print("B is:",args.ParB)
if args.ParA and args.ParB:
    print("the product is: ",args.ParA*args.ParB)


print('over.')
```

but when I run it in my PyCharm, there only print the `over.`

[image]

Comment: Good thing you mentioned PyCharm.  I've seen similar questions where it took a lot of questioning to find that out.  I wonder if there's a way that PyCharm could catch this kind of error, and hold the user's hand.  It's supposed to catch many other kinds of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm will not pass arguments to scripts when you run them. And you have defined both your arguments to be optional.

You need to edit your run configuration to pass the arguments - if you want to run from pycharm.

Go to `test1` (Top right corner) -> Edit Configurations -> Parameters (text box)

And add your arguments there.

```
-a 3 -b 2
```

Then save the config, and run it.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you run the python file did not pass any params.

you shouldn't run it directly.

you can run it in a terminal like this:

```
$ python3 test11.py -a 1 -b 123
```